# Detecting threading safety issues in .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#/.NET analysis tool to find race conditions/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379610/c-net-analysis-tool-to-find-race-conditions-deadlocks)

Are there any tools for automatic detection of threading issues in .NET code?

Comment: I recall FxCop having some rules in this space, and the possibility of additional rules (either yours or a package).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What static analysis tools are available for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38635/1048330) and [C#/.NET analysis tool to find race conditions/deadlocks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2379610/1048330)

Comment: Ok, this is the same. Vote for closing plz.