# How to find the deadlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a application, its consist of lot of custom controls and while process the operation the application is hangs and the deadlock occurs, i can't able to find the code for deadlock, could you please any one suggest how to find the code for deadlock or is there is any tool to find this?

Comment: Breaking on the debugger doesn't show where it's at that point?

Comment: welcome to the joys of programming

Comment: Hi Sami, debugger is not pointing, i have a very large application.

Comment: logging a.k.a. `Debug.Write` is your friend. riddle your code with logs and read the logs

Comment: Is there is any tool is available to find the dead lock?

Comment: Is the deadlock reproducible ? Have you tried simplifying your app (removing user controls / commenting out method calls etc) to narrow things down ? You need to have a general idea on when / how the hang occurs and take it from there. If you're completely stuck then roll up your sleeves and use windbg / sos - but that's not the easiest tool to use - see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

Comment: If you have a simple deadlock, pause execution in the debugger and inspect every thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you check if there is an exception which is thrown on background. In order to turn on the CLR exception to be thrown go Debug/Exception and check the Common Language Runtime Exception check-box. Secondly you can try to pause a debugging session, and try to see where is each thread at the time that the application was dead-locked and research the Callstack. In addition you can trace each place that probably can be a cause to dead-lock.

Here is some SO query that can help you:

1. [C#/.NET analysis tool to find race conditions/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379610/c-net-analysis-tool-to-find-race-conditions-deadlocks).

Here are some tool that in my opinion can be useful in this case:

1. [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) - can help you to debug and manage situation in a better way(allows to trace the code in a better way and more...).

Regards,